# how to read a long value from standard input in java?

Tags: java, input, long-integer

i am using `util.Scanner` to read input from the user. I don't understand how to read a long datatype value.

```
Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
long l=scr.nextInt();
```

I am unable to read 64-bit data using the above code — it just gives me an input mismatch exception.

Comment: there is a nextLong read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `nextLong` method :

```
long l=scr.nextLong();
```